# Keepass 2.0 file attachment security

Tags: keepass

I recently found the ability of attaching files to entries in [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) 2.0: does KeePass just remember the location of files attached to the entry *or* does it encrypt the attached files inside the KeePass database somehow?

Comment: I guess it can be both... Keepass might store encrypted attachments, but also remember the location for (manual) updating.
Actually, I would very much like the second option, see [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178314/keepass-2-storing-linked-files)..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [KeePass documentation](http://keepass.info/help/v2/entry.html):

> File attachments are stored encrypted in the database (like all other database content).

Answer (score 3):

From experience, I can tell you that it embeds the file inside the .kdb. I cannot say for sure that it encrypts them, although I would have to assume so, and would be extremely concerned if it did not (as I understand it, everything inside the file is encrypted).

You can easily test the linking-vs-attaching behavior for yourself by adding a large-ish file and seeing the size of your .kdb shoot up.

Comment: Heh. A strange thing happened when I added a file.. It went down by 3kb. Guessing somehow it found a better way of compressing the data. I'll probably try a really big file latter today though

Comment: Stores the files. I frequently use Keypass attachments. Mostly to store all my key pairs securely in one place; as well as digital scans of some important documents (passport, birth certificate, etc). On any modern PC or mobile, a 4MB keystore isn't a problem; and a single critical file is easier to backup to every conceivable device and medium in my house.