# How does KEEPASS store images, videos and attached documents/items?

Tags: aes, keepass

I have read quite a bit about KEEPASS and how it encrypts passwords. However, the more I read about it, the more I find how it generates and stores passwords - the methodology provided as well as the documentation all point out to methods that KEEPASS uses to protect your passwords. However, there is nothing said about attachments - such as pictures, videos or documents. Is it all encrypted the same way? I suppose everything is done with AES-256, and the "key transformation constant work factor" that I've read about also just applies about the way password is passed on to keepass and applies to attached items too. Am I correct in these assertions? Any additional information would be much appreciated. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File attachments are stored and encrypted in the database, It uses the same method as the rest of the content. It is all embedded the same way. This information is also found [KeePass documentation](http://keepass.info/help/v2/entry.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Keepass 2.0 file attachment security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70466/keepass-2-0-file-attachment-security)

Already answered via Xander

> File attachments are stored encrypted in the database (like all other database content). http://keepass.info/help/v2/entry.html